# AWS S3DirectoryInfo Delete() not deleting

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a pretty straight forward call to delete a folder and all its contents from S3.

**The Call**

`var response = gfAwsClient.S3DeleteEvent(Globals.globalEventPathAWS, "fgevents-lowres-dev", clouddir);`

**The method is:**

```
public async Task<string> S3DeleteEvent(string basedirectory, string bucketName, string folderName)
            {
                if (folderName != null)
                {
                    var dirInfo = new S3DirectoryInfo(client, bucketName, basedirectory + folderName);
                    dirInfo.Delete(true); //set to true to delete everything inside too
                }            
                return null;
            }
```

The value of the concated basedirectory + folderName = `"/Events/01/999/001/"`

And the value of dirInfo = `{fgevents-lowres-dev:\/Events/01/999/001/\}`

It executes, but nothing seems to happen, I get no errors thrown, and I don't even see how to return a good or bad response back.

Comment: Try `Events/01/999/001/` or `/Events/01/999/001` or `Events/01/999/001` (in that order) instead of `/Events/01/999/001/` - does that fix anything?

Comment: Yup that was it.  The leading / I had in the beginning was screwing it up. 
 It's Events/01/999/001

Comment: You're welcome :) enjoy using AWS and .NET!

Answer (score 0):

It does not want the leading "/" as the root.
So for the path I used:

```
Events/01/999/001
```

The full call is:

```
    string basedirectory = @"Events/01/";
    string folderName = @"999/001";
    string pathToDelete = Path.Combine(basedirectory, folderName);
                    var dirInfo = new S3DirectoryInfo(client, bucketName, pathToDelete);
                    dirInfo.Delete(true); //true deletes all files and current folder
```